# sed - why '^[-\s]$' does not match empty lines

Tags: unix, sed

## Objective

Trying to create the **To** file by applying sed on the **From** file, removing:

1. From the 1st line to the empty line
2. Empty lines

**From file**

```
Description:           Master Index of EDGAR Dissemination Feed
Last Data Received:    September 30, 2006
Comments:              webmaster@sec.gov
Anonymous FTP:         ftp://ftp.sec.gov/edgar/
Cloud HTTP:            https://www.sec.gov/Archives/

 
 
 
CIK|Company Name|Form Type|Date Filed|Filename
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1000045|NICHOLAS FINANCIAL INC|10-Q|2006-08-14|edgar/data/1000045/0001193125-06-172516.txt
1000045|NICHOLAS FINANCIAL INC|8-K|2006-07-27|edgar/data/1000045/0001193125-06-154794.txt
1000069|TEXAS CAPITAL VALUE FUNDS INC|497|2006-09-12|edgar/data/1000069/0001000069-06-000017.txt
```

**To file**

```
CIK|Company Name|Form Type|Date Filed|Filename
1000045|NICHOLAS FINANCIAL INC|10-Q|2006-08-14|edgar/data/1000045/0001193125-06-172516.txt
1000045|NICHOLAS FINANCIAL INC|8-K|2006-07-27|edgar/data/1000045/0001193125-06-154794.txt
1000069|TEXAS CAPITAL VALUE FUNDS INC|497|2006-09-12|edgar/data/1000069/0001000069-06-000017.txt
```

## Problem

`^[-\s]*$` does not match the empty lines.

```
$ cat master.csv | sed -e '1,/^$/d; /^[-\s]*$/d'
 
 
 
CIK|Company Name|Form Type|Date Filed|Filename
1000045|NICHOLAS FINANCIAL INC|10-Q|2006-08-14|edgar/data/1000045/0001193125-06-172516.txt
1000045|NICHOLAS FINANCIAL INC|8-K|2006-07-27|edgar/data/1000045/0001193125-06-154794.txt
1000069|TEXAS CAPITAL VALUE FUNDS INC|497|2006-09-12|edgar/data/1000069/0001000069-06-000017.txt
```

However, `^[- \t]*$` does match.

```
$ cat master.csv | sed -e '1,/^$/d; /^[- \t]*$/d'
CIK|Company Name|Form Type|Date Filed|Filename
1000045|NICHOLAS FINANCIAL INC|10-Q|2006-08-14|edgar/data/1000045/0001193125-06-172516.txt
1000045|NICHOLAS FINANCIAL INC|8-K|2006-07-27|edgar/data/1000045/0001193125-06-154794.txt
1000069|TEXAS CAPITAL VALUE FUNDS INC|497|2006-09-12|edgar/data/1000069/0001000069-06-000017.txt
```

## Question

Please explain the reason. In my understanding `[ \t]` is the same with `[\s]`, hence not sure why.

Comment: `\s` is not special in sed regular expressions.

Comment: If you want to delete empty or whitespace-only lines, use `/^[[:space:]]*$/d`

Answer (score 1):

The basics of the special character in regexp list block. `\` is not special in the regexp list `[]` except `\t` and `\n`.

`[\s]` is the same with `[s]`. Need to use the POSIX character classes for other special characters.